# Remove key pair from running EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, key-pair

I lost my .pem file due to which I am not able to login to my ec2 instance. Luckily I had my machine key added to the auth_keys file, so I am able to login using it. I removed the master pub key from the auth_keys file and restarted sshd service. But my colleague who is having the master.pem key file is still able to login to the instance. Am I missing something to disable the complete access to the instance using the master.pem file.
Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the auth_keys file exist in two places?  Maybe you deleted the wrong one?  Maybe you should try changing the fingerprint of the server.

New commentary: removing the public key doesn't affect the private key.  The master pem file may be associated with the private key.  If the private key remains, other public keys will still work.  The topic says "Remove key pair."   But the description doesn't indicate removing the private key.

Comment: Nope, i deleted the only existing file